# Is it common for teachers to take standardized language tests in order to memorize them and post YouTube videos giving their contents?

Tags: exams

In preparing for the Chinese HSK6, I stumbled upon videos such as these: [1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uNtfwuOoEfg), [2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hJqk-s7xazs), [3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B--49PPp86Y).  In these videos, Chinese teachers take the HSK6, then upload videos describing its contents and giving answers.  These particular videos are uploaded on the same day as the exam (from last month's HSK).

I'm trying to figure out how I feel about these videos ethically.  Clearly, I'd be at a disadvantage if I choose not to use them.  And the chinesetest.cn website uses past exams as "mock" exams, so I could get an equivalent experience through accepted means.  So I'm leaning towards "it's okay".  At the same time, it feels like the exams are being "leaked".

Thus I'm interested in whether or not the same practice takes place for other language exams:

**Question**: Is it common for teachers to take standardized language tests in order to memorize them and post YouTube videos giving their contents?